# CSS цвет рамки кнопки

Tags: html, css, button, border

Всем привет! Вопрос такой: как задать другой цвет левой и верхней рамочки кнопки? Через button:active и outline-color не выходит

```css
body {
  background-color: #1c1c1b;
}

.button { 
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom: #1c1c1b;
  border-right: #1c1c1b;
  border-left-color: #1c1c1b;
  border-top-color: #1c1c1b;
  color: beige;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Вы пишете про рамку (`border`), а стили устанавливаете для внешней границы (`outline`). Для `outline` можно задать цвет, но для всей границы, а не для отдельных сторон и чтобы цвет работал, нужно добавить еще толщину и стиль. Если всё-таки надо менять цвет рамки, то `border-left-color: red; border-top-color: red;`

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий вариант кода для решения Вашего вопроса.

**ВСЕГДА** когда прописываете свойства **border** или **outline** Вы должны  указать для них **толщину**, **форму** и **цвет**, а если не указать, то браузер просто не понимает что ему нужно отобразить.

**Представьте:** Вы задали цвет пикселю, но не выделили ни одного пикселя для отображения, цвет то существует, а вот того, что он должен окрашивать нет, поэтому в Вашем случае и не работало.

Если остались еще вопросы буду рад помочь.

**PS:** Если ответ помог, пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить его как правильный.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<style>
    .img {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #1c1c1b;
    }
    
    h1 {
        margin-top: -165px;
        margin-left: 300px;
        font-size:450%;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: beige;
    }
    
    p1 {
        font-size: 250%;
        font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        color: beige;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-block: 0px;
        line-height: 200px;
    }

    
    .textfield {
        width:175px;
        background-color: #2b2b2b;
        color: beige;
        box-shadow: 3px 2px 1px 0.5px rgb(51, 51, 51);
        border-radius:6px;
        border-color: transparent;
        margin-top:-100px
    }   
    .button {
        background-image: "button.png";
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom: #1c1c1b;
        border-right: #1c1c1b;
        border-left-color:1px solid #1c1c1b;
        border-top-color: 1px solid #1c1c1b;
        color: beige;
        margin-bottom: -200px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .button:focus,
    .button:active {
        outline: 1px solid red;
    }   
</style>    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Weather</title>
    
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/weather/web/weather.png">
</head>

<body>
    <img class = "img" src="weather.png" height="250px" border="0px" vspace="0" hspace="0px" alt="Картинка погоды"/>
    <h1><big>Weather app</big></h1>
    <p1><big>Enter the location below and confirm by clicking the button</big></p1>
    <form>
        <button type ="submit" class="button">
            Кнопка
        </button>
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="textfield" placeholder="Type the city and country">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

outline - это свойство, которое задаёт контур элемента. Контур не делится на верхний, нижний, левый и правый. Это единая линия, к которой может быть применен стиль (контур будет в виде штриха, пунктира, сплошной линии, двойной линии и т.д.), цвет, ширина. И какими бы не были стиль, цвет, ширина контура, сделать его только сверху и слева, сверху и справа, снизу и сверху, справа и слева, снизу и слева, снизу и справа, справа, слева сделать не представляется возможным. Если Вы работаете с outline - Вы получите вот такой эффект. Контур (единую линию) вокруг элемента.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1c1c1b;
}

.button { 
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1b;
  color: beige;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
```

Если же Вы хотите, чтобы при focus и active у Вас была  видна только верхняя и левая ГРАНИЦЫ (ГРАНИЦЫ, НЕ КОНТУР)то это делается следующим образом:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1c1c1b;
}

.button { 
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1b;
  color: beige;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: red;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Кнопка</button>
```